# Is Arzela Ascoli thoerem is only valid for Sup Norm?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Arzela Ascoli theorem gives necessary and sufficent condition of compact subset of $C[0,1]$ with sup norm.

Is it still valid if we consider subset of $C[0,1]$ with different norm?

I had come across this question in solving some problem.

Please give me some suggestion

Comment: I'm not immediately sure about other norms, but Arzela Ascoli theorem definitely works with different topologies, like the topology of compact convergence. (See "Topology" 2nd edition by Munkres.)